# Use both jQuery.checkbox & jQuery.field

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

I am trying to use two jQuery solutions on the one form, but I am unable to get the desired result after working on it for several hours.

The first jQuery solution enables a better look and feel
http://www.envirotalk.com.au/jquery/jquery-checkbox.htm

The second jQuery solution enables a limit to be set on the number of checkboxes selected.
http://www.envirotalk.com.au/jquery/jquery-field.htm

This is my attempt at combining the two.
http://www.envirotalk.com.au/jquery/combined.htm

I believe the problem relates to this line of code, but I cannot be certain.

```
setLimitSelection();
```

The outcome I am trying to achieve.

- Look and feel; jquery-checkbox
- Limit to the number of checkboxes one
  can select; jquery-field
- The error message; jquery-field
- Clearing the extra field value once
  exceeded limit; jquery-field.

If someone has the time to take a look and help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where else would the problem be? We'll need to see your code if you want help. Is it throwing up any errors in the error console?

Comment: Hi sneakyness, the code can be found at http://www.envirotalk.com.au/jquery/combined.htm (have a look at the Javascript within the page). In relation to the error console, sorry I am not with you. I use a text editor to develop and change code. How would I check the error console?

Thanks
zeroanarchy

Answer (score 0):

The two plug-ins are probably conflicting with each other, since the code that you're using is the same as the ones given in the individual examples. For limiting checkboxes that can be selected, you can try this:

```
function setLimitSelection(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        var checkboxes_to_allow = 3;
        if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == (checkboxes_to_allow+1)){
            //show error message
            return false;
        } else {
            //clear message
        }
    });
}
```

I think the code is clear enough to not need comments?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you can solve the problem with a small status variable like checkfield:

```
var checkfield = false;

$("input[name ='name']").limitSelection({

limit: 3,
onfailure: function (n){
checkfield = true;
return false;
}
}).click(function (){
if (field6error)
{   
$(this).checkBox('changeCheckStatus', false);
checkfield = false;
alert("Not more than 3 values!")
return false;
}});
```